# Ag-grid tree view with paging

Tags: javascript, treeview, ag-grid

I have an ag-grid, which has the following gridOptions:

```
var gridOptions = {
    headerHeight: 0,
    columnDefs: columnDefs,
    defaultColDef: {
        initialFlex: 1,
        width: 240,
        resizable: true,
    },
    treeData: true,
    pagination: true,
    animateRows: true,
    rowSelection:'single',
    rowModelType: "serverSide",
    cacheBlockSize: defaultRecordsPerPage,
    paginationPageSize: defaultRecordsPerPage,
    autoGroupColumnDef: {
        headerName: "Accounts",
        cellRendererParams: {
            checkbox: true,
            suppressCount: true,
            innerRenderer: function (params) {
                // display employeeName rather than group key (employeeId)
                const entity = params.data;

                var details = `${entity.AccountName} [${entity.AccountNumber}]`;
                if(entity.IsMoneyAccount) {
                    details = `${entity.AccountName} [${entity.Currency}, ${entity.AccountNumber}]`;
                }

                return details;
            },
        },
    },
    isServerSideGroup: function (dataItem) {
        return dataItem.Children;
    },
    getServerSideGroupKey: function (dataItem) {
        return dataItem.ID;
    },
};
```

and the `dataSource` function looks as follow:

```
function createServerSideDatasource() {
    return {
        getRows: function (params) {
            var data = {
                itemsPerPage: defaultRecordsPerPage,
                page: (params.request.endRow / defaultRecordsPerPage) - 1
            };

            if (params.parentNode.data) {
                var children = params.parentNode.data.Children;
                params.successCallback(children, children.length);
            } else {
                myApi.get(data, {
                    url: "/home/accounts-tree-data",
                    success: function (response) {
                        params.successCallback(response.data, response.recordsTotal);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `defaultRecordsPerPage` is set to 2 so I can test the content with multiple pages.

When I expand one of the Parents the children repeat after the second element. For example:

```
- Parent 
-- Child1
-- Child2
-- Child1
-- Child2
```

I expect to get the following result:

```
- Parent 
-- Child1
-- Child2
-- Child3
-- Child4
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this behavior expected?
The data I receive from my request to the server a list of parents which contain their children, I don't want to make an extra request each time I expand the Parent element, that's why I check the parentNode.data property.